# How to apply Melt Area Detection Index to MODIS imagery?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, modis, erdas-imagine, band-ratio

I am working with some MODIS imagery for a project (I'm relatively new to remote sensing) using MOD09GA, and hoping to apply a melt area detection index (MADI) to images to calculate melt day length for different years. This was done in [a paper by McCabe et al in 2010](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1362&context=usdoepub), where they present the equation for this. It simply divides band 1 by band 7, but I have no idea how to do this in ArcMap or ERDAS Imagine.

Looking for tips on how I would go about this. Do I need to create a composite bands image, or use raster calculator?

Comment: You can just use raster calculator. If you have either a multi-layer raster you or two rasters, a simple division using r.calculator would do it

Answer (score 1):

Calculating MADI will produce a single band image. You can accomplish this calculation in the raster calculator. This is the expression you will need to use in the raster calculator if you are using composite (stacked) imagery:

```
"your_modis_image.tif - Band_1" / "your_modis_image.tif - Band_7"
```

Otherwise, if your imagery is composed of non-stacked bands:

```
"your_modis_image_band1.tif" / "your_modis_image_band7.tif"
```